# jetty-runner /stats endpoint only available at localhost, how to open to network?

Tags: java, jetty

From [the jetty-runner documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/runner.html) the --stats flag will allow the display of statistics under `http://localhost/stats`.  But AFAICT that's not available to any other interface, and I'm not seeing a way to configure that.

Is there a way to open /stats up to the network?

Here are the details:

Start jetty, running the grobid war, with "stats" on and un-passworded, without any --host flag

```
$ java -jar jetty-runner-9.2.3.v20140905.jar  --stats unsecure grobid-service-0.2.10.war  &
[10] 29549
$ 2014-11-07 09:07:31.255:INFO::main: Logging initialized @47ms
2014-11-07 09:07:31.261:INFO:oejr.Runner:main: Runner
2014-11-07 09:07:31.383:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.3.v20140905
2014-11-07 09:07:31.416:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6981170d{/stats,null,AVAILABLE}
Nov 07, 2014 9:07:33 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  org.grobid.service
Nov 07, 2014 9:07:33 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class org.grobid.service.GrobidRestService
Nov 07, 2014 9:07:33 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
Nov 07, 2014 9:07:33 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
2014-11-07 09:07:35.160:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1a108c98{/,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-grobid-service-0.2.10.war-_-any-6704428208347840300.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{file:/home/kevin/temp/xx/grobid-service-0.2.10.war}
2014-11-07 09:07:35.161:WARN:oejsh.RequestLogHandler:main: !RequestLog
2014-11-07 09:07:35.180:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@10a54c39{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2014-11-07 09:07:35.180:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @3998ms
```

I can request the grobid service from the external network interface, no problem

```
$ wget -qS 'http://192.168.122.171:8080' -O - | head -5
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Fri, 07 Nov 2014 17:10:19 GMT
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  Content-Type: text/html
  Last-Modified: Tue, 04 Nov 2014 21:03:04 GMT
  Content-Length: 7772
  Server: Jetty(9.2.3.v20140905)
<!DOCTYPE XHTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Grobid Web Application</title>
```

but "/stats/" is a 503-Service Unavailable on that interface

```
$ wget -qS 'http://192.168.122.171:8080/stats/' -O - | head -5
  HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
  Date: Fri, 07 Nov 2014 17:11:41 GMT
  Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
  Content-Length: 294
  Server: Jetty(9.2.3.v20140905)
```

although "/stats/" *is* available on localhost

```
$ wget -qS 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/stats/' -O - | head -5
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Fri, 07 Nov 2014 17:15:30 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
  Content-Length: 1342
  Server: Jetty(9.2.3.v20140905)
<h1>Statistics:</h1>
Statistics gathering started 9185ms ago<br />
<h2>Requests:</h2>
Total requests: 3<br />
Active requests: 1<br />
```

In response to Joakim Erdfelt's suggestion below, adding --host 0.0.0.0 or --host 192.168.122.171 like this

```
java -jar jetty-runner-9.2.3.v20140905.jar --host 192.168.122.171 --stats unsecure grobid-service-0.2.10.war  &
```

still result in 503-Service Unavailable.  I know that `--host 192.168.122.171` has *some* effect because with that flag the working page at `/` is unavailable when queried at `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone will face same issue as @KevinG here is my solution, since i found this topic trying to solve same issue, after thinking for some time, i have found the way how to overcome the limitation, that stats can be called only locally from machine/server that jetty-runner is running on.

First setup nginx on same server/machine where you are running jetty-runner. Make sure you use proxy forward in nginx config to forward all traffic to jetty-runner (localhost:8080). Your nginx by default should be listening on port 80. Open http://localhost:80 from your host server/machine/local pc and nginx will forward your request to jetty-runner and will return reply. Same will work with /stats/. Open http://localhost:80/stats/ on your host/local pc and you will reach stats page of jetty-runner.

nginx config:

```
server {

listen 80;
server_name localhost;
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.html index.htm;

## default location ##
location / {
  access_log off;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you enable statistics via `jetty-runner`, using the `--stats` command, you are essentially adding a [`StatisticsHandler`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/StatisticsHandler.html) to the running Server and all of its connectors.

Now, with `jetty-runner` you only ever have 1 connector, and you control its listening `--port` and `--host` with the command line.

If you specified only `--host localhost` then it will only collect statistics for localhost interface.

If you want it to listen to all interfaces, then use something like `--host 0.0.0.0` for listening on all IPv4 interfaces (if using IPv6, then you'll have to use the IPv6 equivalent)

Comment: Without any --host flag, jetty was listening on 0.0.0.0.  *With* the --host flag, I can *restrict* what interfaces jetty listens on, but they have no effect for the /stats/ url.

I've appended details of my attemps and the responses in my question above.